# USB stick autoejects itself directly after insertion

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, windows-10, usb, usb-flash-drive

Yesterday, my USB flash drive came up with a strange behaviour: **It autoejects itself directly after insertion.**

The device is a Sandisk Cruzer 32GB. The last action I did was removing `autostart.ini` from the stick (I think this is irrelevant but I am going to mention it).

After inserting the stick, the Windows sound for recognizing a USB device is played. If I am fast enought I can see the device under ejectable devices. However after approximately five seconds the sound of ejection is played and the device is lost (I've recorded and uploaded the sound sequence [here](https://clyp.it/iobdootw)).

I also checked Device Manager and Disk Management but my USB flash drive is not there. I'm therefore unable to format my USB flash drive.

I also tried to access the USB flash drive with Windows 7 and Ubuntu (on other devices) but the result was always the same.

I searched Google but found no information about the problem like I have. Is my problem caused by software or is it a hardware defect? In the event that the error is caused by software - is there a way to fix it? Not least through losing all the data.

**EDIT:**

During the five seconds the device is connected, I can see the device in the USBDeview - tool:

[image]

Comment: Does this occur when you plug it into another computer?

Comment: No @Don't Root here plz... I tried it on different devices - the result always the same behaviour.

Comment: While connected do you see you memory stick present in list of drives the disk management? run->diskmgmt.msc

Comment: No @alljamin - the device does not appear

Comment: Backup your data and format your stick. If the problem persists, it's because your pendrive's firmware is corrupted. If so, the best thing to do is buy a new one.

Comment: How to format if I have absolutely no access ?

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg, when you said "autoejects", do you mean that the system issued explicit "eject command", or the USB drive self-disconnects due to some perceived (or real) hardware-related communication fault?

Comment: I have no idea if this is a hard- or software problem ...

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg, these questions and slow debug is exactly what we are trying to figure out here. Did you try the suggested software tools to see what the system sees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are getting a popup telling you it's safe to unplug the device, then the sound you're hearing is probably just the hardware disconnect sound, and not an actual Eject.

So if you've tried it in multiple USB ports, machines, and OSs, and it keeps happening, then it sounds like you simply have a broken USB flash drive.  Try a different (known-good) flash drive, and if it works, throw out the faulty SanDisk and get a replacement.

Comment: What sound is there when you soft-disconnect your usb drives? I've never heard anything like this

Comment: I've added a link of the sound sequence to my question @JaredT ... I never changed my windows sounds so all sounds are default.

Comment: Since we have no windows logs or else yet, can you identify the sound? Say, plug a known good pen drive (not the Sandisk one), then unplug. Is the sound the same one?

Comment: yes - the same sounds!

Comment: Then it means that some USB protocol has not done well. It would be interesting to find out if this is due to signal deterioration, or some logical mishandling/corruption. Did you try USB2-only ports? Can you get an old USB1.1 hub and try the interface in FS mode? Try to see what is logged by NirSoft utility USBDeview.exe, and what USBview.exe show upon plug in.

Comment: @Ali Chen: I have checked this - I can see the device for 5 seconds. I have added a screenshot to my question.

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg, the USBDeview tool shows that the last successful plug-in did occur on Oct.4, or 24 days ago. Since than the system failed to see your drive. What do you see in USBview?

Comment: Absolutely Nothing ...

Comment: It is impossible. If a device tries to connect, and, as you say, stays for 5 seconds, the USBview should see the event (if autorefersh is enabled). The latest USBview tool has a function to "reset device". You can determine which physical port on your computer is connected to which controller (by plugging good devices). Then plug your bad device, and issue "device reset" to the root controller. The re-discovery and attempt to re-enumerate should occur. If nothing will occur, then you are out of luck, throw the Sandisk into trashcan.

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like you have a virus infection. The Sandisk is notoriously known for puting some questionable self-executable malware on its flash drives, for so-called security or whatever. There used to be a special hack tool to remove that stuff in the past.

Comment: I think this should not be the problem. I am using the device for quite a while. I also formatted the stick serveal times.

Comment: Windows 10 doesn't allow executables to run automatically from USB devices. Plus, is this an answer on how the OP can rectify his problem or your opinion?

Comment: Windos10? Of course... Regarding the SanDisk, I am reflecting the facts. And the facts are that the SuperUsers have posted more than 300 issues related to malfunction of SanDisk memory products. Apparently the Sandisk is getting too inventive but has a flaky firmware which goes bad under some electrical/time condition. Now my opinion: do not buy Sandisk USB flash drives.